# Spring JPA massive insert of complex relation hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a big set of data (computation result of MDP algorithm) which I need to save to relational database (MySQL).

The problem is, that entities are interconnected between them. The hierarchy goes like that *OptimizationRun* -> *State* -> *Action* -> *Transition* -> *State* 
The number of states is about 11000 and the number of actions and transitions is about 300 000 for each run.

Now, if I go standard JPA route of cascading, the write takes about 5 minutes, because each *State* (together with it's actions and actions' transitions) gets written separately. I want to optimize the relations, to get advantage of batch insert functionality. For this purpose I have disabled cascading and tried to save first the *OptimizationRun*, then all the states. Unfortunately during states persistence I receive the following exception

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: mdp.optimizationapp.domain.PersistentAction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: mdp.optimizationapp.domain.PersistentAction`

Now here is the question, how do I arrange my hierarchy properly, to be able to optimize inserts?

Comment: [This](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update) might help.

Comment: For tasks like this I'd go with `JdbcTemplate` instead of JPA.

Comment: @JensSchauder well, if Spring Data developer says that, I guess I will go with his advice :-)

Comment: 8-) Well a Hibernate or Eclipse Link developer might have a different opinion, but obviously mine is right ;-)